# How to find decimal places lower than 2 and fill them with zeros in R

Tags: r, join, raster, geotiff, lidar

I'd like to merge two datasets based on a common column. Dataset A is a geoTIFF image, representing RGB values of an area. Dataset B is a point cloud with xyz values of the same area.

I want to merge the RGB info in the image to the 3d data. I thougth to use the x y coordinates of the two datasets (which are in the same coordinate system).
I wrote a script inspired by code snippets found in stackoverflow, but I need to implement my whole code (sources are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248029/how-to-concatenate-numeric-columns-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173692/how-to-return-number-of-decimal-places-in-r), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833784/how-to-extract-values-from-rasterstack-with-xy-coordinates)).

The issue is that the x y coordinates in thwe two files have different precision (decimal numbers). Dataset A has 0 to 2 digits; dataset B has much more. I rounded the dataset B digits to be 2. Now, I'd like to pad with zeros when the digits of datset A are less than 2, so that the final merge will hopefully work.

Would a simple if statement be fine considering that my datset has >280000 rows? Or should I go for indexing? Anyway, I'm fairly new in using R, so I hope the possible posters woud help me with a code example. Below is my code:

```
require(raster)
require(rgl)

setwd("C:/my/folder")

# Read tiff file
img <- stack("image.tif")

vals <- extract(img, 1:ncell(img))
coord <- xyFromCell(img, 1:ncell(img))
combine <- cbind(coord, vals)
remove(vals)
remove(coord)

# read POINTCLOUD and assign names
lidar <- read.table("lidardata.txt")
names(lidar) <- c("x","y","z")

decimalplaces <- function(x) {
  if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
    nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}


# HERE I SHOULD PAD THE LIDAR VARIABLE WITH ZEROS IN DECIMAL POSITIONS WHEN THE DIGITS ARE LESS THAN 2!!!
lidar$xy <- do.call(paste0,lidar[,1:2])

combine$x <- round(combine$x, digits = 2)
combine$y <- round(combine$y, digits = 2)
combine$xy <- do.call(paste0,combine[1:2])

finaldata <- merge(combine,lidar,by = 'xy', all = FALSE)
```

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by @Heroka, here is also an example of how the lidar (the dataset A) looks like, and how it should be after padding it with zeros.

**LIDAR** (original)

```
x     y     z
12    9     87
11    23.4  100
```

**LIDAR** (altered, and with 'xy' column added for joining)

```
x     y     z     xy
12.00 9.00  87    12.009.00
11.00 23.40 100   11.0023.40
```

**EDIT 2**

I somehow managed to retrieve the number of digits in all x and y of my 'lidar' variable (dataset B) with `counting <- sapply(lidar$x, decimalplaces)`
In the example above (LIDAR-original), this would give [0 0] for the first (x) column, and [0 1] for the second (y) column. I should be able to find each row in my x y datset with a value of 0 or 1 as digits (not 2) and pad with 0 like in LIDAR-altered above.

Comment: Would 'sprintf("%02f",....) help? Like `sprintf("%.02f",0.1)`?

Comment: I don't know, I think that is a matter of printing, or I did not understand your suggestion. Anyway, I am now looking at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317452/how-to-count-how-many-elements-satisfy-a-condition-in-an-idiomatic-way), which seems to indicating a way to do that. Thanks

Comment: I understood your question as 'I need to have a way to ensure two digits and thus to pad with zeroes', which is what sprintf can do (you can save the output to a variable). Could you maybe extend your question with some parts of lidar and combine, and what your intended result is?

Comment: We appear to have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you need to pad with zeros. If the coordinates are of class `numeric` and both were rounded using `round` (which should avoid issues of floating point precision) you should be able to just merge by them. Something like this:

```
lidar$x <- round(lidar$x, 2)
lidar$y <- round(lidar$y, 2)
combine$x <- round(combine$x, digits = 2)
combine$y <- round(combine$y, digits = 2)

finaldata <- merge(combine, lidar, by = c("x", "y") , all = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. No, only one was rounded using round (the image, or dataset A), because it had 5 or more digits, while the other has 0 to 2 digits. Of course, the less digits, the less precise the merge will be (and the more data I will loose because there will be a lot of duplicated coordinates).

Comment: Well, then you need a completely different approach (such as interpolation maybe). Pasting together x and y coordinates is definitely not the way to go nor is padding with zero (which doesn't make a difference at all).

Comment: Why not? As far as I know, if I simply have the same xy (converted as character, and that's why I would need the same number of digits) it should work with a simple join. I tried it without padding and I got 4035 rows in my finaldata. I thought the many rows I lose were due to the join not considering the xy in dataset A with 0 and 1 digits, and datset B with 2 digits.

Comment: The basic message of my answer is that (i) you should definitely not use text processing functions for numeric values (we have `round`, `floor`, etc.) and (ii) you can merge by more than one column.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the way I am rtying to achieve what I want is surely not the best one. Anyway, both the sprintf approach and your answer were useful to made me understand I should try another way. I accept your answer. Guess I will go with this (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138611/assigning-rgb-values-from-geotiff-image-to-lidar-data-using-r).